# Vim cursor trail

Tags: vim, caret

I was ricing my i3 config when suddenly, a cursor trail effect got toggled? In vim, when I move the cursor around (not the mouse cursor, the caret), a trail of 4 carets follow it, each a little more transparent than the other. This also applies to text, where when I delete something, a fade effect-ish thing happens, the text slowly fades away. As cool as this is, I want to know how this got turned on and how I can customise it. [image: Screenshot]

EDIT: Upon reloading i3, this effect disappeared, but I still want to know what caused it, I also had launched picom in that session.

EDIT 2: After watching some tutorials and coming back to change the config, it's back! It doesn't seem to be stably set.